# Is there any limitation for integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is JavaScript's Max Int? What's the highest Integer value a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to)

Hi,
I am assigning a php value(obtained from POST) to a javascript variable. When I alert this value,only 17 digits appear. Rest are replaced by 0. However when I echo the post it is fine.
The code is below:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];  // value here is 12345678901234567890
?>
<script>
var d = <?php echo $data ?>
alert(d);  // value here is 12345678901234567000
</script>
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: what is the actual value obtained from the POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)

> The MAX_VALUE property has a value of
>   approximately 1.79E+308. Values larger
>   than MAX_VALUE are represented as
>   "Infinity".

See an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/8ZcV3/)

Comment: That's the maximum real value, but because all integers in JavaScript are represented as 64-bit doubles, the maximum integer value you can store is 9007199254740992.  The maximum safe integer value you should store is 9007199254740991, which is 2^53-1.  What you're looking for is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Javascript number reference;

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference

From within the reference you can see that type integer is accurate to 15 digits.